# Why is conjugate gradient descent a better option than gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, conjugate-gradient

From what I understand, we use the [conjugate gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) method to solve a linear equation or to optimize a quadratic equation. Why is it more efficient in solving those problems than the [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)?

Comment: Basic Conjugate Gradients (CG) solves $Ax=b$ for symmetric, positive definite $A$ in $n$ steps. Steepest descent only uses gradient information at a point but works for any differentiable function. The first picture on the Wikipedia page illustrates the difference in these cases. Loosely speaking, CG works better because in $n$ steps it creates a model of the Hessian (in this case the $2$nd derivative of ${ 1 \over 2} x^T A x -b^Tx$). CG can be extended in many ways to solve general $Ax=b$ (GMRES) and it can be modified to handle general functions (See Fletcher-Reeves or Polak-Ribiere).

Comment: The "$n$ steps" philosophy presented in most textbooks only tells a small part of the story.  On the one hand, in practice orthogonality is lost well before $n$ steps happen for real-life large scale problems. On the other hand, CG converges much faster than gradient descent before the "$n$ steps" are reached, see the classical convergence rate estimates for CG/steepest descent for convex quadratic problems in terms of the condition number of the Hessian.